# Custom Checkbox tick not consistent on Edge Browser

Tags: css, checkbox, microsoft-edge

I have tried several attempts to make the custom checkbox look consistent across all browsers. The only browser which i am facing problem is of Edge.
I am using decimal code for the tickmark which appears proper in all the major browsers. But for Edge i have to change the font family as Edge browser adapts the Segoe UI Symbol Font. When changing the font the appearance of the checkbox changes and it does not look consistent.

Try running the below code without the font family: Segoe UI Symbol; That is how my original checkbox looked.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: auto;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+.tick_mark {
  color: #16a0de;
}

input[type='checkbox']+span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.tick_mark {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  padding: 0px 1px;
  color: white;
  margin: 6px 4px 6px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Segoe UI Symbol;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input name="postSelected" class="NonUnSaved" id="chkBlog" type="checkbox" value="4">
  <span class="tick_mark">&#10004;</span>
  <span class="btntooltip" data-val="checkboxTest">Text 1</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Looks exactly the same here. Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0. Segoe UI Symbol font is the same.

Comment: The size of the border changes when you would remove the font

Comment: K, i don't understand the question. Why u removing it?

Comment: Ok to add more clarity. Remove the font Segoe UI Symbol for tickmark.. So thats how the checkbox originally looked like. But after adding the font 'Segoe UI Symbol' the appearance of the checkbox border changed, the shape of the border would look like rectangular

Comment: And you want it to look like...? It's clearer but still don't get exactly what you want. You're saying what's happening, I get it, but what do you need?

Comment: In Chrome and FF, with the font, the box is rectangular (upright); without the font it's square. In Edge, with the font, it's rectangular (same as the others); without the font it's **still** rectangular but sideways, and the checkmark is very different.

Comment: I want it to be sqaure not in rectangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: auto;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked+.tick_mark {
  color: #16a0de;
}

input[type='checkbox']+span {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.tick_mark {
  padding: 0px 1px;
  color: white;
  margin: 6px 4px 6px 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Segoe UI Symbol;
  position: relative;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + .tick_mark:before {
    content: '\a0';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: -2px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input name="postSelected" class="NonUnSaved" id="chkBlog" type="checkbox" value="4">
  <span class="tick_mark">&#10004;</span>
  <span class="btntooltip" data-val="checkboxTest">Text 1</span>
</label>
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained what you changed from OP's code in the question; "try this" doesn't really teach anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to experiment with padding. This makes a better square in Edge:

```
.tick_mark {
    ...
    padding: 0px 2px;
    ...
}
```

You will have to search for how to apply different css to Edge only but i think it's still possible.

You might not be able to make them all *exactly* the same, but very close.

Comment: I have fine tuned this a little bit. I have posted it in fiddle. Just curious how can i align the tickmark inside the border
https://jsfiddle.net/faLte40y/